# How can I trigger manually a Firebase onNewToken call?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When my Android app uses `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()` for the first time, the registered `onNewToken` method gets called. But how can I trigger this event manually while my activity is already running and logged in, so as to simulate some other security event that may have forced clients to refresh their token?

Ideally this should be an external event outside of the application, like going to some online Firebase console where I can purge client identifiers or reset them.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to delete old instance id and after that, get id using `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId();`.

Example:

```java
public static void resetInstanceId() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
                FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: i think the point is, how to force call method onNewToken. The problem would appear if application was upgrade and we put fcm on that new version.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. Every time you call this code you get token.

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                return;
            }

            // Get new Instance ID token
            String token = task.getResult().getToken();

            // Log and toast
            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```